# Change height of rows based on item depth in QML Treeview

Tags: delegates, qml, treeview, spacing

I am trying to change the height of rows in my TreeView based on the item depth in the tree.  The itemDelegate has access to the depth property (so I can change height of the item), but the row height can only be set from the rowDelegate, which can't see item depth.

As you can see from example I need to change row heights to match depth.  How can the rowdelegate determine the item depth from the model?

```
Component {
    id: delegateMenuItem
    Column {
        height: 100  // No effect
        spacing: 20  // No effect
        bottomPadding: 20 // No effect
        Rectangle {
            border {
                color: "blue"
                width: 2
            }
            color: "red"
            height: itemText.height * 2
            width: 300
            Text {
                id: itemText
                text: qsTr(styleData.value)+"-"+height
                color: "white"
                font.pointSize: fontSize(styleData.depth)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the `itemDelegate` instead?

Comment: My code above IS the itemDelegate.  I also have a rowDelegate which just sets the height of the row.  I can't figure out how to allow the itemDelegate to resize the row it displays in.

Comment: So to confirm, setting the `implicitHeight` of the `itemDelegate` using `styleData.depth` does not give you the correct size?

Comment: @Pooya - that sets the height of the ITEM, not the ROW.  So there is lots of space on either side of the item if I reduce item height but not row height.

Comment: I assumed if you didn't set the `rowDelegate`'s `height` it's `implicitHeight` would be set to the maximum `implicitHeight` of items in row. But I haven't tried it. Just FYI I have done this with the new `TreeView` from the marketplace using `rowHeightProvider`.

Comment: If you don't set a row height (in the rowDelegate) you get the result shown in my question.    (Each row is a fixed default height).  I want the row height to resize to the height of the (single) item in the row.  That's what I am asking for a solution to.  How is the TreeView in the marketplace different from the QQC1 TreeView?

Comment: Did my answer below answered your question?

Comment: Your answer doesn't work with QQC1.  So I finally gave up and bought the QQC2 TreeView plugin.  Is there online documentation for the QQC2 version?  (I can't find it)

Comment: In your code above you are not setting `implicitWidth` for Component. Did you try changing that? The documentation is in the readme I think: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-extensions/qttreeview.git/about/

It also inherits from `TableView` I think: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html

Answer (score 1):

Using `TreeView` from QQC1, I suggest that you try setting the `implicitHeight` for the `itemDelegate` and not setting any height for the `rowDelegate`. So try changing your snippet to:

```
itemDelegate: Rectangle {
    id: delegateMenuItem

    border { color: "blue"; width: 2 }
    color: "red"
    width: ...
    implicitHeight: styleData.depth * ...
    
    Text {
        id: itemText
        
        anchors.fill: parent
        ...
    }
}
```

(In your current implementation `delegateMenuItem` does not have any `implicitHeight`. Meaning its `height` is probably 0. Also the `ColumnLayout` as you are using it is useless so I have removed it.)

I have not tried the above. However I have tried doing what you want to do with [`TreeView` from Qt marketplace](https://marketplace.qt.io/products/treeview). It is designed to work with QQC2 and is based on `TableView` from QQC2 so you can use `rowHeightProvider`.